# Porcentajes en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en la que me muestre todos los meses del año y el total de los tres porcentajes que estoy seleccionando por mes, y le estoy dando una condición para filtrarlo por año, pero resulta que yo tengo solo datos del 2018 mas no del 2019 y al yo ejecutar la consulta me muestra los mismos resultados para los dos años cuando debería no mostrarme nada en el 2019, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
  SELECT MesEfic, SUM((TotalEjec*100/TotalProg) + (TotalPerAprob*100/TotalPerCap )+(TotalPerAsis*100/TotalPerProg)) / 3  as Porcentaje
        FROM [Evaluaciones].[dbo].[CAP_EfectividadProg], CAP_CoberturaProg, CAP_EficaciaProg
        WHERE CAP_EfectividadProg.Año = 2019 AND CAP_CoberturaProg.Año = 2019 AND CAP_EficaciaProg.Año = 2019
        AND MesCober = 'ENERO' AND MesEfec =  'ENERO' AND MesEfic = 'ENERO'
        OR MesCober = 'FEBRERO' AND MesEfec =  'FEBRERO' AND MesEfic = 'FEBRERO'
        OR MesCober = 'MARZO' AND MesEfec =  'MARZO' AND MesEfic = 'MARZO'
        OR MesCober = 'ABRIL' AND MesEfec =  'ABRIL' AND MesEfic = 'ABRIL'
        OR MesCober = 'MAYO' AND MesEfec =  'MAYO' AND MesEfic = 'MAYO'
        OR MesCober = 'JUNIO' AND MesEfec =  'JUNIO' AND MesEfic = 'JUNIO'
        OR MesCober = 'JULIO' AND MesEfec =  'JULIO' AND MesEfic = 'JULIO'
        OR MesCober = 'AGOSTO' AND MesEfec =  'AGOSTO' AND MesEfic = 'AGOSTO'
        OR MesCober = 'SEPTIEMBRE' AND MesEfec =  'SEPTIEMBRE' AND MesEfic = 'SEPTIEMBRE'
        OR MesCober = 'OCTUBRE' AND MesEfec =  'OCTUBRE' AND MesEfic = 'OCTUBRE'
        OR MesCober = 'NOVIEMBRE' AND MesEfec =  'NOVIEMBRE' AND MesEfic = 'NOVIEMBRE'
        OR MesCober = 'DICIEMBRE' AND MesEfec =  'DICIEMBRE' AND MesEfic = 'DICIEMBRE'
        group by MesEfic
        order by DBO.FECHANUM(MesEfic)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la forma en la que está escrita tu consulta, el problema que tienes es que estás mezclando operadores lógicos `and` y `or` de tal manera que el motor los interpreta diferente a lo que, leyendo la descripción de tu problema, entiendo que quieres.

Pero, en mi humilde opinión, **tienes un problema más grave**, que es el que voy a resolver, y por tanto no voy a profundizar en la explicación del primero, más que a mencionar que puedes resolverlo utilizando paréntesis para que el motor pueda interpretar las condiciones de la manera en que tú las estás pensando.

Volviendo a tu principal problema, este es que **no estás haciendo explicita la condición del *join* de tus tablas**. Escribes el *query* con una sintaxis que es previa al estándar SQL de **1992**. Si, 1992, ¡hace casi 30 años!.

La lógica detrás de la manera en la que lo escribes, es realizar el producto cartesiano de todas las tablas involucradas y luego filtrar con la clausula `where` los resultados que sean de interés.

Con la llegada de la *nueva* sintaxis `join` a la clausula from del estándar, en 1992, se hizo posible definir las condiciones con las que cada tabla se integra a la consulta.

El resultado final puede ser el mismo pero, de nuevo en mi opinión, la mayor ganancia está en que podemos dividir la lógica de cómo relacionamos las tablas, con la lógica del filtrado de los resultados.

Por lo mismo, propongo que utilices `join` explícitos, indicando en cada caso la condición que une a las tablas. Esto hará más fácil de leer la sentencia, y casualmente, también resolverá el problema que estás observando.

```
SELECT   MesEfic
       , SUM((TotalEjec*100/TotalProg) + (TotalPerAprob*100/TotalPerCap )+(TotalPerAsis*100/TotalPerProg)) / 3  as Porcentaje
  FROM   [Evaluaciones].[dbo].[CAP_EfectividadProg]
         inner join CAP_CoberturaProg on CAP_CoberturaProg.Año = CAP_EfectividadProg.Año and CAP_CoberturaProg.MesCober = CAP_EfectividadProg.MesEfec
         inner join CAP_EficaciaProg on CAP_EficaciaProg.Año = CAP_EfectividadProg.Año and CAP_EficaciaProg.MesEfic = CAP_EfectividadProg.MesEfec
 WHERE CAP_EfectividadProg.Año = 2019 
 group by MesEfic
 order by DBO.FECHANUM(MesEfic)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Jachguate, me ayudaste a resolver mi problema, funciono a la perfección y tendré en cuenta todos tus consejos.